# Custom serialization of KeyValuePair as single property instead of separate "key" and "value"

Tags: c#, json, serialization

So here's my problem.  I have a class that looks something like this...

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, object> Details { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a basic example of what an instance can look like...

```
var root = new Record
{
    Name = "Root",
    Details = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TestSerialization", 
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IsChild", true),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Child1", "Another KV pair")
        })
};
```

I want to serialize this object to JSON, but I want to modify the process a little bit. So when I serialize this object, I want the JSON to look something like this...

```
{
    "Name" : "Root",
    "Details" : 
    {
        "TestSerialization" : 
        [
            { "IsChild" : true },
            { "Child1" : "Another KV pair" }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it seems like most serializers would serialize the key-value pairs into something like this...

```
{
    //...
    { "key" : "IsChild", "value" : true }
    //...
}
```

Is there a writer or serializer out there that can accomplish this?

Comment: you can directly use `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize, check out the example, i have given.

Comment: both `JavaScriptSerializer` and `JsonConvert`, gave same result, i think better to go with non-3rd party DDL , point is when core functionality is there with `JSS`, then why to go with 3rd party DLL, what say?

Comment: @ArindamNayak "point is when core functionality is there with JSS, then why to go with 3rd party DLL," ... well the functionlaity isnt there? thats what his question is about, no? JSS and JsonConvert are not doing what you want them todo.

Comment: @AlexAnderson, yes i agree , point was JSS and JSON.Net converts to a same format having `KeyValue` which is not required, so still i looking out for helpful option for @Zach

Comment: This can be done using either JavaScriptSerializer or Json.Net via a custom converter.  I've added a detailed answer showing how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) and the built-in .NET [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) can give you the output you want if you are willing to write a custom converter class.  The interface for each framework's version of converter is quite different, but the general idea is the same.  I'll demonstrate both in this answer.

### Using Json.Net

In Json.Net you'll need to implement a [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) class like this.  The `CanConvert` method tells Json.Net what type of object(s) the converter can handle, while the `WriteJson` method handles converting each instance to JSON using the `JsonWriter` and `JsonSerializer` passed to the method.

```
class KvpConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(KeyValuePair<string, object>);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, kvp.Value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a demo showing how to use the converter when serializing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new Record
        {
            Name = "Root",
            Details = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TestSerialization", 
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IsChild", true),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Child1", "Another KV pair")
                })
        };

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new KvpConverter());
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, object> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Name": "Root",
  "Details": {
    "TestSerialization": [
      {
        "IsChild": true
      },
      {
        "Child1": "Another KV pair"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Using JavaScriptSerializer

The .Net version of converter is called a [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  Similar to Json.Net, the `SupportedTypes` property tells the `JavaScriptSerializer` what object types the converter handles, while the `Serialize` method is responsible for reshaping the output.  The main difference is that in `Serialize` you don't have direct control over the JSON output; instead, you build and return an `IDictionary<string, object>` which the serializer then serializes in place of the original object that you are converting.  So not quite as flexible as Json.Net, but it is still enough to get what we need in this case.  Here is what the code would look like for the JavaScriptConverter:

```
class KvpJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new List<Type> { typeof(KeyValuePair<string, object>) }; }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)obj;
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        return dict;
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the updated demo code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new Record
        {
            Name = "Root",
            Details = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TestSerialization", 
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IsChild", true),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Child1", "Another KV pair")
                })
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(
            new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new KvpJavaScriptConverter() });
        string json = serializer.Serialize(root);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

The output is the same as for the Json.Net demo, except that the JavaScriptSerializer does not support indented output.